# Help me identify font in logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Please help me identify the font on this logo where it says 'GlasButzen'. I'm trying to put this font on a new website without the image so it can be crisp and clear.

[image: GlasButzen logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **Britannic Medium,** but it's been stretched. Font-recognition software often seems to have trouble with distortions, even a simple stretch.

[image: Britannic Medium, from MyFonts]

It's available from [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/britannic/) but there are others, including free versions.

Comment: I'm fairly clueless in the font world. Can you please point me to a free version? Preferably one hosted on a CDN.

Comment: Just search for Britannic Medium font.